# fuzzy search with lucene

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I implemented a fuzzy search with lucene 4.3.1 but i'm not satisfied with the result. I would like to specify a number of results it should return. So for example if I want 10 results, it should return the 10 best matches, no matter how bad they are. Most of the time it returns nothing if the word I search for is very different from anything in the index. How can I achieve more/fuzzier results?

Here the code I have:

```
    public String[] luceneQuery(String query, int numberOfHits, String path)
        throws ParseException, IOException {

    File dir = new File(path);
    Directory index = FSDirectory.open(dir);

    query = query + "~";
    Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_43, "label", analyzer)
            .parse(query);

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(index);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    Query fuzzyQuery = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("label", query), 2);

    ScoreDoc[] fuzzyHits = searcher.search(fuzzyQuery, numberOfHits).scoreDocs;
    String[] fuzzyResults = new String[fuzzyHits.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < fuzzyHits.length; ++i) {
        int docId = fuzzyHits[i].doc;
        Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
        fuzzyResults[i] = d.get("label");
    }

    reader.close();
    return fuzzyResults;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

large edit distances are no longer supported by `FuzzyQuery` in Lucene 4.x.  The current implementation of `FuzzyQuery` is a **huge** improvement on performance from the Lucene 3.x implementation, but only supports two edits.  Distances greater than 2 Damerau–Levenshtein edits are considered to rarely be really useful.

According to the [`FuzzyQuery` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html), if you really must have higher edit distances:

> If you really want this, consider using an n-gram indexing technique (such as the SpellChecker in the suggest module) instead.

The strong implication is that you should rethink what your trying to accomplish, and find a more useful approach.

Comment: Thanks, this already helps a lot. I try to find entries in a rdf-graph (from dbpedia) with 1.7 million entries. The entries I look for can consist of several words and usually the query has a lot of spelling errors. Another problem is that in german you often can write words separated or concatenated. Therefore I need a greater distance. Do you know a more appropriate approach than what i try now?

Comment: SpellChecker might be a good approach.  [Metaphone](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html) can also be very helpful in dealing with misspellings.  As far as words being separated or concatenated, if it's pretty standard, you would probably benefit from using [`GermanAnalyzer`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanAnalyzer.html), which incorporates a StemFitler that should handle that sort of thing, I would guess (I don't know the details of German stemming, though).

Comment: It really stinks that they removed the inefficient way. SpellChecker is not a query so for APIs that take queries as arguments and hide the Lucene readers and searchers (Neo4j) you are left with a crippled app on upgrade.