# How to retrieve only one of a group of similar strings in a list of strings in java

Tags: java, string, fuzzy-search

How to retrieve only one of a group of similar strings in a list of strings in java.

I have an  list of text data (length of list is ~ 60000)(stored as strings) within which there are groups of text which are very similar to each other.
From this list I would like to create a new list that only has 1 element for each group of similar list elements

Simplified example:

```
the boy ate an apple
boy ate apple
the boy ate apple
```

Should only have 1 of the above in the new list

My general approach is to have 2 lists: 
the original list and a new list that will hold the unique list

```
For each text in original_list
    for each utext in the unique list
        if similarity(text, utext) > threshold (threshold can be 90%)
            break
        else
            is_similar = false
    end for

    if is_similar = false   
        add text to unique list
end for
```

For the similarity function I have used simmetrics Levenshtein distance java library.
However I eventually run into java heap space issues even when I increase the jre memory to 6GB

I have also removed stopwords and converted to term vectors using sparse matrices. However, this is very slow.

I do think I can use the override `equals()` and `hashcode()` option as since I am fuzzy matching I cannot guarantee that the `hashcode()` will be equal for strings that are only similar.

Can anyone suggest a more efficient approach to my algorithm please? I am a little rusty with data structures and have been racking my brain and searching online for a solution.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks

Comment: You can use [Lucene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746476/fuzzy-search-with-lucene).

Comment: Thanks user880772. Lucene is brilliant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Lucene, as suggested, to index each string and this made the overall performance of checking similarity much better!

I did come across another suggested alternative [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851582/is-there-an-efficient-algorithm-for-fuzzy-deduplication-of-string-lists) that looks like it might have worked but did not try it as I got what I needed from Lucene.

Thanks!